# Can i recover deleted IAM user on Amazon?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I accidentally deleted a user account on IAM, can i still recover it?
I think it was binded on a bucket which affect the automation now since it was already deleted

Comment: i don't think so.

Comment: You should be able to recreate the lost IAM user quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

If the user or role you created had was in-use by some resource (example: EC2 instance with said attached account) by default, it can't be deleted until you remove the resources that depend on that role. However, if there were no resources attached to that user or role the delete process would go through. In your case, the user should have not been deleted.

Source:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/the-iam-console-now-helps-prevent-you-from-accidentally-deleting-in-use-resources/

Comment: I think the question is referring to an IAM User rather than an IAM Role.

Comment: The AWS policy applies to users AND roles, I edited my answer to be more concise. Thanks for pointing that out!